# Windows Forms - detecting button click from a panel inside the form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have `Windows Form` named - `Form1` and inside `Form1` I have a panel named `panel1`. I use this panel only to add `buttons` in him. For now there are exactly 9 `buttons` but I intend to change their number dynamicly if this has something to do with my current problem. What I need is way to detect a when a button from this panel is clicked (I have other buttons too but, they are in `Form1` outside the panel) and also to know exactly which button was clicked.
I tried this:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HI" + sender);
        }
```

As you can see, it's not much, but was enough to see that I can't do that using `pnael1's_click` event. Using this code I get the message box when I click anywhere in the panel except the buttons. So how can I do that. Is it possible to do it from inside `panel1` or I should group those buttons using another approach but it's important to be able to keep the difference between those buttons which are now in `panel1` and the other buttons I may (and in in fact I do have)?

Comment: you need to use event handler...this is a good tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566617/c-how-to-create-an-event-and-listen-for-it-in-another-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you aren't adding controls dynamically over time, and the number of buttons is fixed as soon as the form is initialized, you can use this to add a click event handler to all buttons within a panel:

```
foreach (var button in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Click += HandleClick;
}
```

Comment: Well, this answer my direct question so I'll accept it, but I do indeed intend to add buttons dynamically so can you suggest a better approach to handle this task?

Comment: OP states he *is* adding them dynamically.

Comment: @retailcoder It's unclear if he's adding a dynamic number entirely at the start of the application, or if he's adding them over time, after the form is initialized.  This covers the first case.

Comment: @Leron Add the click handler any time you dynamically add a button.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I think I got some idea how to deal with this so thanks for the help.

Comment: How to tackle the case if controls are getting added dynamically over time ?

Answer (score 4):

When creating the dynamic buttons, you register that button instance's *Click* event and attach to an event handler (a single handler can handle all buttons' click event):

```
var dynamicButton1 = new Button();
dynamicButton1.Click += MyButtonClickHandler;
```

As long as `MyButtonClickHandler` has a signature that's suitable for a `Click` event (that's any method returning `void` and taking an `object` and an `EventArgs`, the handler should respond to a dynamic button's click event for as long as the button instance exists.