# Multiple click events get fired for dynamically created controls over time

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

I have a following situation in my Visual Studio 2022 Windows Forms applications.

I am creating panels after each button click in the FlowLayoutPanel and in each of those panels I am adding controls like text boxes and buttons.So the panels will be increasing after each button click.

My objective is to create a panel after a button click and each time a button is clicked a panel is created having multiple controls in it. Then I will catch click events for each of the buttons in the panels, so that , for example , If a specific button gets clicked in a specific panel , I should know which button was clicked and then I will get the values of other controls like text boxes from that panel and display them. In the meantime I also want to open another form from the button click that will ask for the editing of the labels in the specific panel and after entering the values will update labels in  the specific panel.

**Following is my Effort**

So I have been able to create controls after a button click inside each of the panels  and each time a button is clicked a new form appears that ask values and then a panel with those values of labels and buttons gets created. I also tried to catch the click events of the buttons inside each of the panel in a FlowLayoutPanel.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public int counter = 0;
        public string text1Data = "";
        public string text2Data = "";

        public Panel singlePanel;
        public FlowLayoutPanel mainPanel;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        
        public void createPanel(string label1Data,string label2Data)
        {
            counter += 1;
            string panelName = "panel" + counter;


            Label lblText1 = new Label();
            lblText1.Text =label1Data;
            lblText1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            lblText1.Name = panelName+"_label1";
            lblText1.Text = label1Data;
            lblText1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 5);
            lblText1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 100);

            Label lblText2 = new Label();
            lblText2.Text = label2Data;
            lblText2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            lblText2.Name = panelName+"_label2";
            lblText2.Text = label2Data;
            lblText2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 5);
            lblText2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 100);



            Button btnSelect = new Button();
            btnSelect.Name = panelName+"_buttonSelect";
            btnSelect.Text = "SELECT_Panel_" + counter;
            btnSelect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(350, 5);
            btnSelect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);

            Button btnUpdate = new Button();
            btnUpdate.Name = panelName+"_buttonUpdate";
            btnUpdate.Text = "UPDATE_Panel_" + counter;
            btnUpdate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(500, 5);
            btnUpdate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);

            Button btnDelete = new Button();
            btnDelete.Name = panelName+"_buttonDelete";
            btnDelete.Text = "DELETE_Panel_" + counter;
            btnDelete.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(650, 5);
            btnDelete.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);





            Panel panelSample = new Panel();
            panelSample.Name = panelName;
            //panelSample.BackColor = Color.Black; 
            panelSample.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 10, 60);

            panelSample.Controls.Add(lblText1);
            panelSample.Controls.Add(lblText2);

            panelSample.Controls.Add(btnSelect);
            panelSample.Controls.Add(btnUpdate);
            panelSample.Controls.Add(btnDelete);

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panelSample);
            mainPanel = flowLayoutPanel1;


            foreach (var panel in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
            {
                
                string name = panel.Name;

                foreach (var button in panel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
                {

                    if (button.Name == name+"_buttonSelect")
                    {
                        button.Click += Button_Click ;
                    }
                    if (button.Name==name+"_buttonUpdate")
                    {
                        button.Click += Button_Click1;
                    }
                    if (button.Name==name + "_buttonDelete")
                    {
                        button.Click += Button_Click2;
                        singlePanel = panel;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var label in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                {

                    if (label.Name==name + "_label1")
                    {
                        text1Data = label.Text;
                    }
                    if (label.Name==name + "_label2")
                    {
                        text2Data=label.Text;
                    }

                }

            }

        }


        public void updatePanel(string data1, string data2)
        {
            Form3 form = new Form3();
            form.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblFirst.Text = text1Data;
            lblSecond.Text = text2Data;
        }

        private void Button_Click2(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mainPanel.Controls.Remove(singlePanel);
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
        }


        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 createForm = new Form3(this);
            createForm.Show();
        }
    }
}


  namespace WinFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public static Form1 parentForm;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        parentForm = form;
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text!="" && textBox2.Text!="")
            {
            parentForm.updatePanel(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        }
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {

        public static Form1 parentForm;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form3(Form1 form)
        {
            parentForm = form;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            parentForm.createPanel(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problems:**
I am getting bunch of problems

1. I am getting cascased firing of button click events. For example after having three panels inside the FLowLayoutPanel , when I clicked a button to open a form for the select or update, It opened multiple copies of the form. So that means muliple event listeners of the same control are being fired because of the loop.
2. The select functionality gets broken after having added multiple panels , as only the select works for once  and  display information of labels and on subsequent click I am not being able to display the values of the labels .
3. For update functionality I created a public method and exposed it to the update form but here again , I am confused as to how to update a values inside a specific panel .
4. The delete button inside a panel is also not proplery working as after having couple of panels the delete does not work on the very first panel.

[image: Multiple Forms getting fired after a single click]

I worked in winforms realted applications like 06 years ago so I pardon if my question seems rubbish to the developer community.

Regards

A solution to a related problem is discussed here at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609380/windows-forms-detecting-button-click-from-a-panel-inside-the-form) in the answer but the exact case of how to develope an event listener for the dynamically adding controls over time was not dicussed.

Comment: Do you know what this: `mainPanel.Controls.Remove(singlePanel);` does? -- Before you think about doing something like `singlePanel.Controls.Clear()`, don't.

Comment: It deleted a panel from the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: No, it doesn't *delete* anything. `Dispose()` *deletes*

Comment: In my case, I just again tested, after creating multiple panels , it was only being able to delete the last panel. The other panels could not get deleted.

Comment: Again, you're not *deleting* a Control by removing it from a collection. In this case, it's simply not shown anymore

Comment: I believe the main problem is that I am getting multiple event listener for the same control and for removing the control , I  followed this documentation for removing the control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that a Control is removed from the Collection, not that the Control removed doesn't exist anymore. It still exists, so do the event handlers you have used to subscribe to events. You have to `Dispose()` of a Control to *delete* it -- Build a method that accepts a Control as argument: in the method, loop the child Controls, remove the event handlers, then dispose of their Parent -- As a suggestion, you should build an UserControl instead of *sparse* child Controls (still you need to dispose of it)

Comment: Thanks a lot , I was able to successfully attach and detach events and for this I made functions that can attach detach events .  Now the cascading event firing issue is gone , Now comes the problem of how to extract controls values from a specific panel upon clicking the button on that very panel.

Comment: => *Build an UserControl instead of sparse child Controls*